# Sending email through corporate account using Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I want to send emails using my corporate account. However, I get the following error in Python:

`SMTPAuthenticationError: 550, b'5.2.1 Mailbox cannot be accessed`

If I open up my corporate account on outlook, I am able to send emails through it using Powershell script. But Python script only gives me the error above.

The following is my python code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
mail_content = "Hello, This is a simple mail. There is only text, no \
attachments are there The mail is sent using Python SMTP library"

sender_address = 'corporate_email_account'
sender_pass = 'XXXX'
receiver_address = 'corporate_email_account'

message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python. It has an attachment.'   
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587) 
session.starttls() #enable security
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```

Why is Python unable to send the emails? Could this be a firewall issue or maybe Microsoft doesn't allow this behavior in python scripts, but does with Powershell scripts?

Comment: SMTP and Exchange MAPI are different protocols. SMTP may not be enabled for your account on the Exchange server -its optional. Powershell is probably speaking the MS proprietary MAPI protocol.

Comment: I've just copied your code and used my 365 corporate account data and it have worked fine (no proxy, python 3.7.5).